# Asp.net core web API DeserilizationObject not working

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ASP.net core web api and angular 10. When I make a post request from angular project, it is passing the correct json object. It hit the POST method on my api side. Than I try to deserializeObject but it is throwing error.
ERROR:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<API.ViewModel.EmpDepViewMode>(string)' has some invalid arguments'
```

JSON I am passing

```
    {
"Employees": [
    {
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "yearlySalary": "50000",
    "numberOfPayCheck": 26
    }
],
"Dependents": [
    {
    "Type": 0,
    "Name": "Maria Smith"
    }
]
```

}

EmpDepViewModel:

```
    public class EmpDepViewMode
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();
    public List<Dependent> Dependents { get; set; } = new List<Dependent>();
}
```

Employee class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int yearlySalary { get; set; }
    public int numberOfPayCheck { get; set; }
}
```

Dependent class

```
    public class Dependent 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DependentType Type { get; set; }
    
}
```

POST Method

```
public IActionResult Post(dynamic employeeDependent1)
    {
        EmpDepViewMode employeeDependent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmpDepViewMode>(employeeDependent1);
         return Ok(employeeDependent )
     }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: it can be `cors` problem, but it's hard to tell without sharing code

Comment: If your API is expected to receive an `EmpDepViewMode` object, why not just apply [`[FromBody]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0) with specify the parameter type such: `public IActionResult Post([FromBody] EmpDepViewMode employeeDependent1)` and you don't need to deserialize it *manually* as the .NET Core runtime will handle and read the body for you.

Comment: For testing purposes, in your Post method, try to convert your JSON to a string and check whether you see any issue there. It could help you know whether something invalid got appended to it.

Comment: the value of "yearlySalary" in JSON is provided as string but in object model is int.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix action, you are trying to deserialize data the second time, since it was deserialized already automaticaly.  And it doesn' t make much sense to make it dynamic since you use already EmpDepViewMode

```
public IActionResult Post(EmpDepViewMode employeeDependent)
{
       return Ok(employeeDependent )
}
```